# On social login reactive forms fields get error

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using Angular with reactive forms. On my sign-in page, there is an option to sign in using FB or Google account. But, the minute the user clicks on one of these options the input fields get invalid and turn red. Any solution for this issue? Why does it happen?

```
popupWindow(provider: string) {
const fromState = this.store.selectSnapshot<any>((state) => state.userState).data as AccountModel;
const countryCode =  fromState && fromState.countryCode || environment.defaultCountryCode;
const dualScreenLeft = window.screenLeft;
const dualScreenTop = window.screenTop;
const width = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : screen.width;
const height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height;
const left = ((width / 2) - (600 / 2)) + dualScreenLeft;
const top = ((height / 2) - (500 / 2)) + dualScreenTop;
const url = `${this.baseUrl}/api/Account/SocialExternalLogin?countryCode=${countryCode}&provider=${provider}&response_type=token&client_id=_self`;
const features = `location=0,status=0,scrollbars=yes, width=${600}, height=${500}, top=${top}, left=${left}`;
const newWindow = window.open(url, provider, features);

window['authCompleted'] = (localToken) => {
  this.setToken(JSON.stringify(localToken));
  this.store.dispatch(new fromAccount.UserAccountDetails());
  this.dialog.closeAll();
};
```

}

Comment: I think your buttons are type=submit by default change it to type=default and check

Comment: Can you show the html?